# Include row number as column in MySQL INSERT

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to insert the row number of a row as it is inserted in MySQL? Something like:

```
INSERT INTO users SET uid=ROWNUMBER(), email="joe@example.com";
```

If not, is there any other way that you would suggest to create a uid based on the entry number?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL (along with most RDBMS) does not have any internal row number or order.  However, you can create an `uid` column which will auto increment every time a new record is inserted.

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD uid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
```

Now when you do an `INSERT`, MySQL will automatically increment the `uid` column.

```
INSERT INTO users SET email="joe@example.com"
```

Comment: Thanks! Originally when I first came across this problem, that is the exact solution I was looking for. I'm glad you found it even though I'd forgotten about it.